# KO optionsValue not binding completely?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the following:

```
    <select data-bind="options: colorOptions, optionsText: 'DisplayName', optionsValue: 'Id', value: Color.Id, optionsCaption: 'Select...'"
```

Where `colorOptions` looks like this

```
[
    {

        "DisplayName": "Blue",
        "Id": 22028
    },
    {
        "DisplayName": "Yellow",
        "Id": 22029
    }
]
```

And `Color` looks like this (object with observable properties):

```
{
    "DisplayName": "Blue",
    "Id": 22028
}
```

This seems to be working, except for the fact that DisplayName on the color is not updating when I make changes - only the Id is.  Do I have to manually re-assign DisplayName, or can I tell knockout to replace the whole object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the value is set when you make changes with this binding handler, and since you have assigned Color.Id to the value, this is what is updated when you change the options.

The fact you have set optionsValue to be 'Id' tells the binding handler that the value comes from the Id property on the datasource, so if you want to update the whole Color proprety you need to do the following

- Remove `optionsValue: 'Id'` this means that the value is set to the entire item within the array, not a single property on it
- Update `value: Color.Id` to `value: Color`
- You may need to change Color on your model to be an observable if it isn't already. This is only required if you want 2 way binding (i.e. the ability to set the options value by changing this property)

Comment: Fantastic.  I almost have this working... saves are working great, but initial bind is now broken - the dropdown always displays 'Select...' despite binding to a Color.  Any idea why?

Comment: Are you seting the value of Color from an item in the colorOptions array? The value must exist in this array, it's not sufficient to set it to a new object with properties set to the same values

Comment: var self = this, id = 22028; self.value(ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.unwrap(self.colorOptions), function(c){ return c.Id === id; }));

Comment: I have a dto with an object that contains the same properties.  Does this mean I must iterate over the array we get back from the server while binding?  Seems messy :/

Comment: As far as knockout (or javascript for that matter) is concerned, 2 objects with values set to the same thing aren't the same object.. its a bit of a pain that you can't override this but you only need one line to pick a valid item from the array